# Find and replace excel code with variable expressions

Tags: excel

I have a function that looks like this:

```
    =SUMPRODUCT(ISNUMBER(Search(File Link, Set Value)))
```

What I'm looking to do is to replace the values in the file link with another value. However, there are many file links which makes it impossible to search and replace all the different links. I am also looking to only replace file links in search functions which searches for 1 particular set value.

Is there a way of doing so?

The value I intend to replace the file link with is {0,0, 0 ... one hundred times, 101, 102 ... 120}, only start counting upwards from 101. I am also struggling to find a good way of creating this array.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the first part of your question you might be able to get away with using an asterisk (*) in the search.  an asterisk will count as any number of unknown characters.

so `=SUMPRODUCT(ISNUMBER(Search(*, Set Value)))`

should find:

=SUMPRODUCT(ISNUMBER(Search(File Link, Set Value)))

=SUMPRODUCT(ISNUMBER(Search(File Link 2, Set Value)))

=SUMPRODUCT(ISNUMBER(Search(Incoherent gibberish, Set Value)))

If you only want to change the links with a certain beginning you could change it to

`=SUMPRODUCT(ISNUMBER(Search(File*, Set Value)))`

this would find the first 2 of my suggestions but not the 3rd.

as for the issue of creating the array you could try

```
={ & rept("0,",100) & 101 ... 120 & }
```

or you could simply fill a column with 100 cells with 0, and then put 101 and 102 in the ones below it, so that you can drag it down to 120.  then you could type

`CONCATENATE(TRANSPOSE(A1:A120))`

in your Set Value section (this range would be wherever you put the list of numbers).  The issue with this is that your numbers end up in quotation marks, which may or may not cause issues for you depending on your task.